# HybridSort worst and bestCase example

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have n integers in the range [0;n^2] and need to sort them using HybridSort. As far as I know the integers for hybridSort need to be in the range of [0;1] which I can accomplish by dividing through 1/n^2.

My script says that the best-case scenario is *O(n)*.
Example: *x_i =n/i* 
which would go into the i-th bucket and therefore the runtime is linear in n.

What would be an example for the worst case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for the worst-case would be if the  values are not evenly distributet and land all in the same bucket.
So if you have 10 values you want to sort out of numbers from 1-100.
your numbers are: A=[97,92,96,83,98,95,91,94,99,90]
All Numbers will be sorted into the same bucket, which means they have to be ALL sorted by Heapsort in the next step.

The best case in contrast is, when every value gets sorted into a different bucket, which means you don't even have to sort with heapsort at all in the next step.